# Opening Load Bearing Wall

Tags: walls, load-bearing, remodeling, beam

I  have a home built in 1956 that has a load-bearing wall that is about 2ft off the main support beam in the basement. There is currently a 30" opening in wall with 2x4 header. I would like to extend the opening to 72" and support with an appropriate size lvl beam. The width of the load is 24ft wide but supports a second story and rafter roof. There has been no evidence of cracking with the current wall. Are posts in the basement required?

Comment: would you really not use posts if some stranger on the internet said that you can? .... hire a structural engineer

Comment: If you do a search on this site you will find many many questions about load bearing walls. And they all have the same response, **you need an engineer to tell you for sure** and if you want an **educated guess** you need to provide all the details you can and photos of the space above etc. Search for those questions to see how to edit your question to be better

Comment: Because you need to consult an engineer / architect to make sure all is taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I plan to hire a structural engineer but just wanted to get a general consensus. I am sure the house wouldn't meet code today, although it has stood the test of time and passed all initial inspections.

Comment: @jpringle8 Not enough info for a "general consensus"

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You can't just drop posts anywhere, because there probably aren't footings at that location. The issue is load transfer _to the existing beam_. You'll either need to post an array of clear photos or get someone on site. Or both.

Comment: Is the width of the load 24’ on both sides of the beam or just one side? (Btw, half that span will transfer to an outside wall...so the tributary area would be 12’ from the 24’ span.)